# how does notifyItemChanged(pos) is not passing the correct postion to the onBindViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an app that the user is presented with a list of items, and they can press like or share. When they press like the image of the ImageButton is changed as it should but I logged the output of the position in onBindViewHolder and it is different from the exact postion I actually clicked

This is in my onCreateViewHolder doing some calculations here it outputs the correct position of the clicked item

```
public void onHeartPress(View imgB,int pos)
{
    Log.d("Postion",pos);
    notifyItemChanged(pos)
}
```

Then I try to log the position when notified

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder,  int position)
    {
       Log.d("Postion",position);
    }
```

The position that is passed to onBindViewHolder is not correct for example if an item at position 0 is pressed the position 5 and 0 will be passed to onBindViewHolder not only position 0

Comment: Is there is a header or something like that? What do you mean is different from the exact position?

Comment: Can you please add some code so we can figure it out the problem?

Comment: Okay I will add the code

Comment: I added the code please chk it

Comment: @yanozai can you add your `Adapter` code together with the `ViewHolder`?

Comment: but the onBindViewHolder is recycling, it is normal that the log will be display for position 0 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why both position 0 and 5 are called is because it's a recyclerView. It recycles your views. If you want to only notify the view which as been checked, you should probably create an array of booleans with the size equal to the size of the adapter you are using. You can then change the value from your heart pressed method

```
public void onHeartPress(View imgB,int pos)
{
    Log.d("Postion",pos);
     yourArray[pos] = true;
     // if you want to change the others to false;
     for(int i = 0; i < yourArray.length(); i++{
           if( i != pos ){
           yourArray[pos] = false;
            }} 
    notifyItemChanged(pos)
}
```

your adapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder,  int position)
    {
         if(yourArray[position])
       Log.d("Postion",position);
    }
```